# Count up on form submit

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a form and I want to add a value to my form on page load. This way I have a unique identifier each time the form is filled in by someone.

So in my form I have:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="uniquecount" value="{counter}" />
```

How do i build this counter script on page load to add it to the value of #uniquecount?

```js
var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');

if (n === null) {
   n = 0;
}

n++;

localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = n;
```

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. If someone else fills the form in on a different computer while someone has the form loaded, then their counter will get out of date.

Comment: To add on Quentin's words: the counter should be implemented on the server-side - not on the client side. And even then, you should be careful in considering the scenario there are multiple servers running in parallel!

Comment: `localStorage` is ***local***. So, when there are multiple clients, it won't work. Also, anyone can edit your site's HTML, or even bypass it, and therefore submit anything to your server, which imply large security problems, if haven't taken care of.

Answer (score -2):

As others suggest, maybe not the most smartest thing to do. 
Currently, if I load the form form the value is = 0. Next time I visit it, it will be 1. 
But if you visit it, it also will start from 0.

If you're using a build tool, you could look at something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Otherwise (although still far from perfect), you could use a timestamp in MS:
`performance.now()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

In that case we have to open the form at exactly the same time in MS to get the same value.

Comment: Downvoted within 10 seconds after posting. Then also explain.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but others may have done so because it's never a good idea to verify things, or generate identifier on the client side.

Comment: Absolutely true (as said). But also not an aswer to OP's question